# Parallel faces planar capacitor: condition $d\ll \sqrt A$

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

In my college notes from about 30 years ago, if I have a plane capacitor with parallel faces of distance $d$ and area $A$, I found written
$$d\ll \sqrt A$$

> What is the mathematical/physics reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the mathematical/physics reason?

The capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor as a function of the physical characteristics of the capacitor is given by the equation

$$C=\frac{\epsilon A}{d}$$

where $A$ is the area of the plates ($m^2$), $d$ is the plate separation ($m$) and $\epsilon$ is the electrical permittivity of the dielectric between the plates (Farads/m).

The equation assumes that the electric field between the capacitor plates is confined to the volume of the space between the plates. See FIG 1 below which shows a cross section of a parallel plate capacitor with all the electric field lines confined to the volume between the plates.

In actuality, however, the electric field lines are not confined to that volume. They extend to the space beyond the edges, as shown in FIG 2. This is referred to as the "edge" or "fringe" effect. The fact that the field lines extend beyond the edges of the plates means the actual capacitance is greater than that predicted by the above equation, since the effective area of the plates is greater than the actual area. To calculate what the actual capacitance would be involves  complex mathematical modeling. If you are interested in that, see http://www.drjamesnagel.com/notes/Nagel%20-%20Numerical%20Poisson.pdf.

To get around this, one can minimize the influence of the edge effects by reducing the percentage of the total number of field lines that are outside the volume between the plates. This can be accomplished by having the separation the $d$ between the plates be much less than the linear dimensions of the plate, as shown in FIG 3.

If the plates are circular, then the edge of the plate, shown in FIG 3, would equal its diameter. Thus a condition for reducing the influence of the edge effects for a circular plate is to have the separation $d$ be much less than the diameter of the plates $D$, or $d<<D$.

Now, getting to the equation $d<<\sqrt A$ that you found in your notes. It's obvious that it assumes square plate capacitor since the edge shown in FIG 3 would be the same for each side of the plate. Moreover, for the same plate area there’s less fringing in the case of square plates than rectangular plates. That’s because fringing occurs at the perimeter and the perimeter of a square is always less than a rectangle of the same area.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Hello dear Bob D. Thank you for your kind and courteous response which I appreciate. But if the plates are square can the condition be proved?

Comment: What condition?

Comment: That that i have written in the title

Comment: Ok, I will revise my answer to elaborate

Comment: I Will wait. Thank you 

Comment: @Sebastiano Did my revision answer your follow up comment?

Comment: See additional information I added at the end regarding fringe effect of a square versus a rectangle

Comment: Bob hiiiii. Yes i have seen and i have upvoted you for other answers.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks. Ciao!